# What is good way to register adjacent HTTP requests with the Spring integration flow

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

What is good way to register adjacent HTTP requests with the Spring integration flow?

My application is:

For the every customer (has it's own flow, which start is scheduled by the poller)

- GET operation 1 in the source application and the result is JSON_1
- POST JSON_1 to the remote system and the result is JSON_1B
- POST JSON_1B to the source application and the result is JSON_1C
- GET operation 2 in the source application and the result is JSON_2
- POST JSON_2 to the remote system and the result is JSON_2B
- POST JSON_2B to the source application and the result is JSON_2C

...

- GET operation n in the source application and the result is JSON_N
- POST JSON_N to the remote system and the result is JSON_NB
- POST JSON_NB to the source application and the result is JSON_NC

The operations 1, 2, ..., n must be in the order

Here is my example program (for the simplicity all the REST calls are for the same class)

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

@Autowired
private IntegrationFlowContext flowContext;

@Bean
public MethodInvokingMessageSource integerMessageSource() {
    final MethodInvokingMessageSource source = new MethodInvokingMessageSource();
    source.setObject(new AtomicInteger());
    source.setMethodName("getAndIncrement");
    return source;
}

@PostConstruct
public void createAndRegisterFlows() {
    IntegrationFlowBuilder integrationFlowBuilder = createFlowBuilder();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
        integrationFlowBuilder = flowBuilder(integrationFlowBuilder, i);
    }
    integrationFlowBuilder.handle(CharacterStreamWritingMessageHandler.stdout());
    flowContext.registration(integrationFlowBuilder.get()).register();
}

private IntegrationFlowBuilder createFlowBuilder() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(this.integerMessageSource(), c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(5000)));
}

private IntegrationFlowBuilder flowBuilder(final IntegrationFlowBuilder integrationFlowBuilder, final int number) {
    return integrationFlowBuilder
            .handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://localhost:8055/greeting" + number).httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                    .expectedResponseType(String.class))
            .channel("getReceive" + number)
            .handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://localhost:8055/greeting" + number).httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                    .expectedResponseType(String.class))
            .channel("postReceive" + number)
            .handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://localhost:8055/greeting-final" + number)
                    .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST).expectedResponseType(String.class))
            .channel("postReceiveFinal" + number);
}
}
```

This program runs the integration flow

```
GET http://localhost:8055/greeting1
POST http://localhost:8055/greeting1 (previous result as an input)
POST http://localhost:8055/greeting-final1 (previous result as an input)
GET http://localhost:8055/greeting2
POST http://localhost:8055/greeting2 (previous result as an input)
POST http://localhost:8055/greeting-final2 (previous result as an input)
```

This is working as expected. But I'm wondering is this good way to do this, because the response from the call `POST http://localhost:8055/greeting-final1` is not used in the call `GET http://localhost:8055/greeting2`. I only want that these calls are in this order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you have everything you needed with that loop to create to sub-flow calls to the REST services. Only what you are missing is a `payload` as a result from the `greeting-final1` which is going to be published with the message to the `.channel("postReceiveFinal" + number)`. The second iteration will subscribe the `greeting2"` to that channel and the `payload` is available for processing here. Not sure how to rework your `flowBuilder()` method, but you just need to use a `payload` from the message for whatever is your requirements, e.g. you can use it as an:

```
/**
 * Specify an {@link Expression} to evaluate a value for the uri template variable.
 * @param variable the uri template variable.
 * @param expression the expression to evaluate value for te uri template variable.
 * @return the current Spec.
 * @see AbstractHttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler#setUriVariableExpressions(Map)
 * @see ValueExpression
 * @see org.springframework.expression.common.LiteralExpression
 */
public S uriVariable(String variable, Expression expression) {
```

to inject a payload to some request param since it is just `HttpMethod.GET`:

```
handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://localhost:8055/greeting2?param1={param1}")
        .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
        .uriVariable("param1", "payload")
        .expectedResponseType(String.class))
```

Comment: The result from the POST to the greeting-final1 is not needed in the GET greeting2. I want to have only operations 1, 2.. n in the order. The technology is new for me and I was just wondering if I have a good solution.

Comment: No, the solution is not good then. You need to take a look into the `PublishSubscribeChannel` or `RecipientListRouter`

Comment: I think so that those classes are not solution. I tried to highlight my solution and edited the initial question. I'm running adjacent operations, which have to be in the specific order. But after some set of three operations is finished the output is not used in the next set of three operations. For example  `JSON_1C` is not used in the operation `GET operation 2`. IntegrationFlowBuilder is working perfectly and I don't currently have any problems, but I was thinking is my solution good.

Comment: As I said you: according your loop logic the result from the last POST is available for the next GET. With that loop you still compose the same `IntegrationFlow` and everything is sequential. Not sure what you are missing, but you just don't use that result. That's all. If you worry about an order, then you good.

Comment: In my example `GET operation 2`  doesn't need `JSON_1C`. I think so everything is ok. The `GET`, `POST` and `POST` inside one operation are in sequence and all operations 1, 2, 3... are in the sequence. Thanks :-)